# Find closest element by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this vote snippet, and I'd like to add a disabled class to the other button than what the user press. For example if user vote + on id 1 post then the - button would get a disabled class, but not the id 2 ones.

```
<span class="pull-right">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="vote" data-id="1" data-type="up">+</a>
              <span id="votes-1">0</span>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="vote" data-id="1" data-type="down">-</a>
</span>
<span class="pull-right">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="vote" data-id="2" data-type="up">+</a>
              <span id="votes-2">0</span>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="vote" data-id="2" data-type="down">-</a>
</span>
```

I already tried several things like .closest().find() but i couldnt make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Traverse up to the parent of the clicked `.vote` element.
2. Use [**.not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and `this` to exclude the clicked `.vote` element.

```js
$('.vote').click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  $(this).removeClass('disabled');
  parent.find('.vote').not(this).addClass('disabled');
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="pull-right">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="vote" data-id="1" data-type="up">+</a>
              <span id="votes-1">0</span>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="vote" data-id="1" data-type="down">-</a>
</span>
<span class="pull-right">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="vote" data-id="2" data-type="up">+</a>
              <span id="votes-2">0</span>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="vote" data-id="2" data-type="down">-</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.vote').click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  $(this).removeClass('disabled');
  parent.find('.vote').not(this).addClass('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use several approaches.

1. The following jQuery code is the shortest one. It takes all siblings and filters them with selector. The only item in array will be another button:

   ```
   $(".vote").click(function()
   {
       $(this).siblings(".vote").addClass("disabled");        
   });
   ```
2. You can also do it this way. It is searching globally through the attribute value. It is good if you will need to disable something else in a document by attribute `id`.

   ```
   $(".vote").click(function() {
       var id = $(this).data('id');
        $(".vote[data-id='" + id + "']").not(this).addClass("disabled");
   });
   ```
3. Another option is traversing up to a parent, taking elements by selector and exlucing current one. Internally, it is almost the same as the first one.

   ```
   $(".vote").click(function() {
       $(this).parent().find(".vote").not(this).addClass("disabled");        
   });
   ```

Choose one which is the most preferrable.